# Birt Report: duplicate pages if content of row is too big

Tags: birt

I use the Birt Report Engine to generate complex PDF (report) documents. My page layout contains grids and tables. The origin of the content of a table row is a user defined xml document. If this content is too long, Birt generates a lot of duplicate pages. Suppose the content of the row would make up 3 PDF pages, then Birt generates 3 times 3 pages with the content:

```
page 1: content part 1, page number 1
page 2: content part 2, page number 1
page 3: content part 3, page number 1
page 4: content part 1, page number 2
page 5: content part 2, page number 2    
page 6: content part 3, page number 2
page 7: content part 1, page number 3
and so on
```

(*page* is the actual page number in the PDF document, *page number* is the number that is shown as a page number on the page)

I already tried the setting

```
options.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
```

with all the available options, but nothing changed the output.

The HTML version of my document looks nice.

Does anyone know how to cope with these duplicate pages?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This may be related to bug in birt: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386238